# import * as angular from 'angular' inside app.module.ts file

Tags: angular, typescript, systemjs

I have upgrade angular1 app to bootstrap with angular2 (upgrade option), but after importing angular with systemJS config:

```
map: {... 'angular': 'npm:angular/angular.js' ... }
```

The browser send error:

```
systemjs.import error: Error: (SystemJS) angular.module is not a function
    TypeError: angular.module is not a function
        at execute (http://msoqa05.devlab.ad:8088/home/bl/app.module.js:88:21)
        at ZoneDelegate.invoke (https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.7.4?main=browser:242:26)
        at Zone.run (https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.7.4?main=browser:113:43)
        at https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.7.4?main=browser:520:57
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.7.4?main=browser:275:35)
        at Zone.runTask (https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.7.4?main=browser:151:47)
        at drainMicroTaskQueue (https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.7.4?main=browser:418:35)
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.7.4?main=browser:349:25)
    Error loading http://msoqa05.devlab.ad:8088/home/bl/app.module.js
```

Maybe I did not understand it, but in order to import angular I need to mapped it inside systemjs.config? Why?

I am trying to downgrade angular2 componenet inside app.module.ts:

```
import * as angular from 'angular'; 
import { downgradeComponent } from '@angular/upgrade/static';

angular.module('myApp')
    .directive(
        'helloWorld',
        downgradeComponent({component: HelloWorldComponent}) as angular.IDirectiveFactory
    );
```

The ts compile is fine with that, but the browser not ok with it and I get this error. angular.module is the basic of angularJS?

Comment: I checked the log:  angular.module is undefined, so I did something wront. angular is defined as a Module

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Doing so solved the problem:
no need to import angular with systemjs.

```
import * as _angular_ from 'angular';

declare global {
  const angular: typeof _angular_;
}
```